# Taskbar and panel icons disappearing

Tags: gnome-panel

On Ubuntu 13.10, after installing VirtualBox Guest Additions, my taskbar and panel icons disappeared and do not come back after a restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a terminal and running the following commands will restart the panel:

```
gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/panel
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel
pkill gnome-panel
```

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=766281